# How to use an include path property in sonar-project.properties for the execution of PHPUnit?

Tags: php, zend-framework, phpunit, sonar-runner, sonarqube

I'm working on a project with the Zend Framework and I need to use the path of the framework as an include path property for launch PHPUnit. It's ok for an execution on my work station.

Actually, the problem is for the execution of PHPUnit in SonarQube analysis. I've create files property like it is recommend : sonar-project.properties and phpunit.xml.dist

The sonar-project.properties file offers some properties for the configuration of PHPUnit.
(in the tab named "Configuring PHPUnit to be run by SonarQube" [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/PHP+Plugin)).

But nothing for use an include path property. I was thinking it can be a property to use with the Sonar Runner but I can't find anything about that.

Versions:

- ZF 1.1
- SonarQube 4.0;
- Sonar Runner 2.3;
- PHPUnit 3.7.28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use :
sonar.phpUnit.argumentLine= --include-path "your_path"